# R: How to write interruptible C++ function, and recover partial results

Tags: c++, r

We are writing an R package, the core of which is written in C++ and basically consists of one long-running loop:

```
void core_func(double* data)
{
    while (!done)
    {
        // update 'data'
    }
}
```

The call is made using R's `.C` mechanism:

```
ans <- .C("core_func", data = as.double(data))$data
```

We would like for the user to be able to interrupt the function, and to recover the partial results (i.e., contents of `*data` at point of interrupt).

**Question:**  Is this in any way possible?

Our efforts to come up with a solution have so far produced [this post](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.devel/27627), which - if interpreted correctly - gives an indication on how to cleanly exit from the loop.

```
void core_func(double* data)
{
    while (!done && !checkInterrupt())
    {
        // update 'data'
    }
}
```

What we haven't figured out, is how to pass the partial results back to the caller (aka. R user).

**Solution:**  It seems the solution was right in front of us all this time.  The approach proposed by Simon Urbanek in the abovementioned post (original post [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2011-April/060702.html)) covers all the bases.  Making use of the `checkInterrupt()` function, the C++ code can be designed to exit cleanly upon a user interrupt; and, most importantly, control is then handed back to the calling `.C` function in R, which can return the (partial) results in an orderly manner.

Thanks to @Jeroen for clearing things up (and for the hint about [searching for code](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=user%3Acran%20R_CheckUserInterrupt%20language%3Ac%2B%2B&type=Code&ref=searchresults) in [METACRAN](http://www.r-pkg.org/))!

*Note concerning the Update in Jeroen's answer:*  We wish to keep the C++ code R-agnostic (precluding a dependency on Rcpp).

Comment: What do you mean by interruptible? Interruptible by the user, for example with a certain keypress?

Comment: @dimm  Yes, that would be the simplest solution from the user's point of view (e.g., hitting `Crtl-c`).

Comment: My suggestion goes to nest the loop inside a `try` - `catch` block and raise an exception when interruption is detected. It should be enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** the easiest approach is to call C++ via Rcpp and check via `Rcpp::checkUserInterrupt`. This automatically raises an exception if a interrupt is pending. See section 2.4 of [rcpp attributes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-attributes.pdf).

**Original answer:** R allows for checking for SIGINT via the C API:

```
R_CheckUserInterrupt();
```

However this function will immediately jump back to the console if an interruption is pending which can leave your C/C++ code in an undefined state.

A trick [suggested by Simon Urbanek](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2011-April/060702.html) is to use the following wrapper code:

```
/* Check for interrupt without long jumping */
void check_interrupt_fn(void *dummy) {
  R_CheckUserInterrupt();
}

int pending_interrupt() {
  return !(R_ToplevelExec(check_interrupt_fn, NULL));
}
```

You can now call `pending_interrupt()` to check if an interruption is pending and deal with it yourself, e.g. raise some special C++ exception or simply return intermediate results. Make sure you read Simon's comments in the post to understand the consequences of this approach.

I have personally only used this via C to [interrupt](https://github.com/cran/curl/blob/master/src/interrupt.c) downloads in the curl package. Perhaps you can [search metacran](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=user%3Acran+R_CheckUserInterrupt+language%3Ac%2B%2B&type=Code&ref=searchresults) for examples that use `R_CheckUserInterrupt` from C++.

Comment: Agreed -- and I have the feeling we have posts here (or maybe on the Rcpp list?) that do this.  I would let go of `.C()` -- it is too constraining and use is generally discouraged by everybody.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel it might be nice to adopt `pending_interrupt` or similar in the Rcpp API.

Comment: Can you file an issue or better still prepare a PR?  ;-)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel  Concerning `.C`: So I've heard, although I'm not clear on the reasons why.  In this particular instance, the C++ code is (almost) completely R-agnostic, and the call from R to C++ is one-shot (i.e., performance is not an issue).  Are there any pressing reasons that have been overlooked?

Comment: See the archives of the r-devel mailing list for some discussion.  Reasons are (as I recall) a combination of a) types too limited ie no complete R types b) efficiency c) control / error propagation.   The use of `.C()` is new code is pretty much discouraged and eg Simon Urbanek said so.

Comment: Also, as discussed elsewhere, with Rcpp you could get automatic interrupt handling without having to do anything from your end.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel  Thanks for the quick answer!  Will reconsider both issues.

Comment: As of 2021, the function Rcpp::checkUserInterrupt() is in section 1.4 of the Rcpp attributes manual.