# Check for abort

Tags: r, rcpp, abort

I used to depend on the package `RcppProgress` to check for user abortion inside a long loop with `Progress::check_abort()`. But I just received an email from the CRAN team to tell me (and to other maintainers) that `RcppProgress` has bugs and will be removed soon in absence of maintainer (actually it seems already removed). Is there another way to check for abortion?

I found that `R_CheckUserInterrupt` exists. How to change my code to use this  function? In [Writing R extensions](http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-exts/R-exts_146.html) the function returns `void` so I do not understand how it works. It seems to exit immediately.

`Rcpp::checkUserInterrupt` seems to present the same behavior. And [R: How to write interruptible C++ function, and recover partial results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40563522/r-how-to-write-interruptible-c-function-and-recover-partial-results) presents a kind of hack not recomented by its author. I would like to exit the loop correctly cleaning object allocated on the heap and returning partial output

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppProgress)]]
#include <progress.hpp>
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP f()
{
  for( int i = 0 ; i < 100000 ; i++)
  {
    if (Progress::check_abort())
    {
       delete some_var;
       return partial_output;
    }
    else
      //do_stuff();
  }
}
```

Comment: While it did disappear, it is already back:  https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppProgress

Comment: Sounds to be back but it is still the version `0.4`. So I guess the archival is still the plan.

Comment: @duckmayr this awnser present a "hack" that the original author would not recommend. And `Rcpp::checkUserInterrupt`seems to return void too.

Comment: @JRR `Rcpp::checkUserInterrupt` raises an exception (and returns void) when the user aborts, just like if the user aborted during `R` code calculation. I would not call this a "hack," though it might not accomplish precisely what you're looking for here. With your edit, I can see you need to return partial output (and on further reflection, this could have been inferred from your code), but if your original post were more clear on your objectives, I would not have thought this was a dupe. The comment has been deleted in light of this information.

Comment: Right I edited my question. Do you know were I can find a doc for `Rcpp::checkUserAbort`. Can't find any result. Regarding the hack I was talking about the other part of the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading the sources of `Rcpp`  I found that `Rcpp::checkUserInterrupt()` throw an `internal::InterruptedException`. This works:

```
for (long i = 0 ; i < 100000000 ; i++)
{
    try 
    {
      Rcpp::checkUserInterrupt();
    }
    catch(Rcpp::internal::InterruptedException e) 
    {
      delete some_var;
      return partial_output;
    }
 }
```

It is slow but exactly like `Process::check_abort`. Optionally, as advised in [Rcpp Attributes](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-attributes.pdf), one can check only every 100 or 1000 iteration to speed up the code.

```
for (long i = 0 ; i < 100000000 ; i++)
{
  if (i % 100 == 0)
  {
     try 
     {
       Rcpp::checkUserInterrupt();
     }
     catch(Rcpp::internal::InterruptedException e) 
     {
       delete some_var;
       return partial_output;
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: And checking every `N` iterations is _exactly_ what the [Rcpp Attributes vignette](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-attributes.pdf) tells you do to in its Section 1.4!